# ImportError: No module named 'twisted.persisted'

Tags: scrapy, twisted

I haved install scrapy on `Python 3.5.2`, but when I exeute `scrapy -v` on command-line, it occurs:

```
>> scrapy -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/usr/local/python3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import _monkeypatches
  File "/usr/local/python3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/_monkeypatches.py", line 20, in <module>
    import twisted.persisted.styles  # NOQA
ImportError: No module named 'twisted.persisted'
```

So I enter ipython3 to ensure whether it's installed porperly:

```
In [2]: import twisted
In [3]: twisted.version
Out[3]: Version('twisted', 15, 2, 1)
```

But when I `import scrapy`, the same as command-line:

```
In [4]: import scrapy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-51c73a18167b> in <module>()
----> 1 import scrapy

/usr/local/python3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py in <module>()
     25 
     26 # Apply monkey patches to fix issues in external libraries
---> 27 from . import _monkeypatches
     28 del _monkeypatches
     29 

/usr/local/python3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/_monkeypatches.py in <module>()
     18 # Undo what Twisted's perspective broker adds to pickle register
     19 # to prevent bugs like Twisted#7989 while serializing requests
---> 20 import twisted.persisted.styles  # NOQA
     21 # Remove only entries with twisted serializers for non-twisted types.
     22 for k, v in frozenset(copyreg.dispatch_table.items()):

ImportError: No module named 'twisted.persisted'
```

I'm so confused, I just want to run a spaider, So help me !

Comment: You can also check package version and other package info by typing `pip show <package_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Your Twisted version is outdated, if you look at `requirements-py3.txt` [file](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/requirements-py3.txt):

> Twisted >= 15.5.0
>   lxml>=3.2.4
>   pyOpenSSL>=0.13.1
>   cssselect>=0.9
>   queuelib>=1.1.1
>   w3lib>=1.17.0
>   service_identity

Where your's is, 15.2.
Currently the latest version 17.1.0 and there are no downsides of running it; Try:

```
pip3 install twisted --upgrade
```